# How to monitor service account activities in google cloud platform

Tags: service-accounts

I created more than 5 service account in GCP to use Pub/Sub services.

Now, I want to delete 4 of the 5 accounts. But I don't know which 4 accounts are not using, which one is active. I don't want to check all the Json config file any more, there are so many servers and applications.

Is there any way to monitor GCP service account activities, such as:

When, Which service account actives in what system from what IP?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From the GCP console left-nav

```
 >> API's and Services 
   >> Dashboard (tab)
     >> Compute API (depending on which API your credentials are using)
       >> All API Credentials (select 1 of your 5 credentials)
```

You'll see the API usage by credential.